# SFDC and REGEX Differences

Tags: regular-expressions

New to REGEX, understand SFDC has some differences though I have not been able to tell why my expression works on test sites but not in a SFDC validation rule.  I need to ensure a record name ends in -SRXXXXXXX, where X are only numeric.
Expression tried: (-SR?)[0-9]+$
Rule: NOT REGEX(Name, "(-SR?)[0-9]+$")

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

In Salesforce formulas, `REGEX` always matches the full string. So you have to formulate your expression to accommodate leading characters. So where you have:

```
(-SR?)[0-9]+$
```

you need instead:

```
.*-SR[0-9]+
```

Note that because of the nature of `REGEX` matching the whole string, you do not need to match end of string (`$`). Note also that you don't need a capturing group (`(...)`, nor do you want the `R` to be optional (according to your description of requirements).

Comment: Thanks, tried that with regextester.com but it is showing (Stevens, -SR4220843a4 Frank id# 112ee3) as matching.  It should not because there is a letter in the XXXXX part and the -SRXXXX is not at the end.

Comment: Added the +$ back and I think I am in business.

Comment: You seem to have missed the point, the `REGEX` function matches only the full string.

Comment: No I understand that now and appreciate you letting me know, I used what you provided and it worked better.  I just needed to prevent a match if anything was after the string I am interested in.  So maybe it could be written better but I can't seem to break this:  ".*-SR[0-9]+$"